# Move from an array of 'labels' to array of equations corresponding to those labels in Python 2.7

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, modeling, numerical-methods

How can I **efficiently** move from an array of essentially labels to equations corresponding to those labels in python 2.7?

This image illustrates what I mean:

[image]

The equations pull values from array x, so "xn" in the image in python terms would be x[n]. As an example, the 0th entry in the label array is "a" which corresponds to the equation 1+xn which would be 1+x[0]. The next is "b" which is x[1]*2.

There are a plenty of ways to accomplish this, but I want to focus on efficiency. The actual arrays have thousands of elements, and this operation is performed thousands of times (each timestep in my model). The x array will be different at each timestep. What I am actually doing is building the diagonals for a tridiagonal matrix based on various boundary conditions.

Can anyone offer some insight better than iterating through the whole array each timestep with a switch case?

Here is an example of me doing it a brute way:

```
'''
Equations corresponding to various labels

a -> 2+x[n]
b -> 3*x[n-1]+2x[n]
c -> 4*x[n]

These are just dummy equations I am making up for the example
'''

x = [4,7,6,6,9,12,4,9,1,11]

labelArray = ['a','b','b','b','c','c','a','b','b','c']

outputArray = []
n = 0
for label in labelArray:
    if label == 'a':
        output = 2+x[n]
    elif label == 'b':
        output = 3*x[n-1]+2*x[n]
    elif label == 'c':
        output = 4*x[n]
    outputArray.append(output)
    n += 1

print outputArray
# outputArray = [6, 26, 33, 30, 36, 48, 6, 30, 29, 44]
```

Comment: If you're talking about time efficiency, think of the usage of `dict`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution I came up with. It should be faster and more concise, though it may not be the optimal solution.

```py
from itertools import imap

# List of values
values = [4, 7, 6, 6, 9, 12, 4, 9, 1, 11]

# A list of corresponding methods for each value, must be same length as values.
# Optionally, you could create the data with the value and method in a tuple
# e.g. [(4, 'a'), (7, 'b') ... (x, 'y')]
# Though if you ensure both lists are of the same length, you can use the zip()
# method, which does the same thing.
methods = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']

# A dictionary with all your equations. You can also define them in a function
# elsewhere and include them like 
# >{ 'a': external_function }
equations = {
    # Lambda is just an anonymous function.
    'a': lambda index: 2 + values[index],
    'b': lambda index: 3 * values[index-1] + 2 * values[index],
    'c': lambda index: 4 * values[index],
}


# Returns an iterator to prevent eating up your memory with one big array.
new_values = imap(lambda x,y: equations[x](y), methods, xrange(len(values)))
print [value for value in new_values]
```

Check out https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html for an explanation of the built in methods I'm using here.
Here's some info on iterators: http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html

Comment: I checked both links you provided, but I don't see "imap" anywhere. My code bugs out when I try your method saying "name 'imap' is not defined". Do I need to import a library or something? Thanks

Comment: My bad, I forgot to add the import statement. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a version of your code that uses a dictionary and a map function. I hope it helps you.

```
functs = { 'a': '2+x[n]',
           'b': '3*x[n-1] + 2*x[n]',
           'c': '4*x[n]'}

x = [4, 7, 6, 6, 9, 12, 4, 9, 1, 11]

larray = ['a','b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']

result = list(map(lambda n: eval(functs[larray[n]]), xrange(len(larray))))

print result

# result = [6, 26, 33, 30, 36, 48, 6, 30, 29, 44]
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution, but actually about 20x slower than my original code, at least on my computer. Thank you for helping, though.

Comment: @Tom Stockman: You may add  `import itertools` and use `itertools.imap(...)` instead of `imap(...)` in BenHohner's solution. It is as fast as your solution.